# Scroll rect unity как скролить сразу 2 панели

Tags: unity3d

Как скролить 2 панели? у меня есть 2 контента со спрайтами, как мне скролить сразу 2 контента по вертикали 1 scroll-ом rect или может другим способом. по горизонтали работает через scrolbar на контенте и привязкой его к scroll rect в horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: Я думаю, что лучше одним

Comment: @Lesh, одним, но каким образом? у меня между этими панелями(контентами) промежуток. я уже не предполагаю как сделать.

Comment: Написать скрипт, который будет получать данные от одного скролла и двигать другой. Или вложить два Content в один скролл.

Comment: @lesh два контента и вложил. спасибо